# Different databases for forms and authentification in django?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

Is it possible to use one database for user authentifications in django and another database for working with django-forms? I work with non-relational data structures and feel comfortable with mongodb forms, but I unable to authorize my users, using mongodb. All posts describing mongodb-authentification with django referer to deprecated modules of mongoengine, which is no longer support django. So I decide to use mysql for user authentification and mongodb as main database, but cannot find information about defining special database for user authorization.

UPD:
I add mysql to setings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    'NAME' : 'my_database'
},
'users': {
    'NAME': 'my_users',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'django'
}
}
```

Migrate:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --database=users
```

It return:

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Then I tried to create a user:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_site.settings
```

,

```
>>> import django
>>> django.setup()
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 159, in create_user
return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 153, in _create_user
user.save(using=self._db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 807, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 834, in save_base
with transaction.atomic(using=using, savepoint=False):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 158, in __enter__
if not connection.get_autocommit():
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 385, in get_autocommit
self.ensure_connection()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
>>>
```

Guys, please, advise me, what was the wrong?

UPD2:
Add a router to settings.py:

```
class AuthRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'users'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'users'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'auth' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auth':
           return True
        return False

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
        database.
        """
        return db == 'auth_db'
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [AuthRouter]
```

Now i have enother error, when create user:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 159, in create_user
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 153, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 766, in save
    using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 267, in _route_db
    chosen_db = method(model, **hints)
TypeError: db_for_write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'model'
```

What's wrong in my router? I copied it from oficial docs.

Comment: Have you looked at the official [Django docs on multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases)? It's quite easy to specify another database specifically for the `User` model, just route all db requests for that model to the SQL database.

Comment: Note however, that you won't be able to let Django handle relationships to your users (cross-database relationships) from your other models. You'll have to handle them yourself, e.g. by adding the references to users yourself and writing methods to query relationships from your `User` model. Also don't forget that any other model related to `User` (all `auth` models and `ContentType`) must be in the same database.

Comment: Thanks, @dirkgroten, I read the docs you mentioned, add mysql, made migration, but failed to add the user.

Comment: That's because you need to setup a database router as well, so that you specify which app uses which database. In your case, you would need to do more or less what's shown in the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example), a bit simplified.

Comment: Thanks, @dirkgroten, I add a router, but now I have enother error, when create a user.